# C++11 regex throwing std::regex_error

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm working on a project that requires me to find all theorems in LaTeX source, but I'm having trouble with `std::regex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
  std::regex r("\\begin{theorem}"); // throws `std::regex_error`

  return 0;
}
```

I've tried constructing this object with different `regex_constants`, but it always throws exceptions.

Doing a search on SO shows that there *were* problems with `libstdc++`, but they were all from several years ago.

I'm using `gcc 5.2.0` from `homebrew`

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Have you put in a try/catch and printed the message on the exception?

Comment: When I catch it, the output of `e.what()` is just `regex_error`.

Comment: Good ole g++. I suspect you need to escape the "{" and  "}" as it's probaly wanting to treat those as meta characters and expecting a number in there instead of text.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Escaping the curlies seems to have worked. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: `{` is a metacharacter, the regex engine expects a count or a range after it, like `{3}`, `{3,}` or `{3,6}` for instance

Comment: c++11 regex uses a direct drop in of Boost::regex engine. It might have changed some things (like properties inside classes) to work properly. Looks like the latest boost regex allows the curly braces to be used as a literal if it is in literal context, without escaping them. Perl has been this way for years. Curly braces have always been an ambiguous metacharacter, unlike parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `{` and `}`. They are being treated as meta characters as in "a{1,3}".